# Best way of resetting an angularJS field

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

in my data I have lat/long values that the user can control via a google map marker.

If the marker is moved this instantly updates the 2 values in the model - but if the user wants to revert back to the original lat/long (resetting the marker) without affecting other data they have updated and wish to keep, what would be the best method to revert that change on those 2 fields?

Would I need to clone the original values on-load in someway and push them back in to the model through jquery or similar based on a reset button?

Comment: Show us some code maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have data and you want to make a "come back" you need to clone original values and to update data if users wants to reset markers. 
Show us your code if you need more help.

Comment: Thats great thanks - I had been looking into angular.copy as a potential method to copy and then retrieve the lat/long values and place in the active model. I will investigate this a bit more. thanks